# Gear for outdoor music recording

Tags: field-recording, music

I'm looking for a gear setup that I could make a live recordings of various musicians and bands outside in various locations

I have tried to do some research but I found it quite difficult because most of the results refer to ambient nature sound recordings (even though my searches were very specific)

I want to start off "small" to see if this project lifts off so I don't plan on heavy expensive gear (I Would say my budget is around 1500e )

I'm looking for a humble USB audio interface.
I was thinking at the Zoom Livetrak l-12 as it can be used as both a mixer and an audio interface.
Altough I'm not sure if it's the correct answer for my needs, because I could just go with a focusrite 18i20 and leave the rest for the DAW

Also I'm looking for Mics that could perform well outside, they would probably shutgun mics?
few shure sm58/57, and some other large diaphragm so I could cover any situation.

I would love to hear your thoughts and advices

By the way, I'm working with a fine laptop and I'm thinking of powering it all with a power bank

Answer (score 1):

My two cents on this.

Record stereo with two small condensors. Skip multi mic setups. Leave all large diaphragm mics at home. Set up the musicians and mics to get a good sound. Do not try to mix to PA and record at the same time ( until you have a lot more experience ).

Get a field recorder. Leave the computer at home and postproduce there. I found a very nice used Sound Device Mixpre 3 for the equivalent of about 400 USD (not the latest model hence the price ). There are quite a few very good second hand field recorders out there.

Make a good stereo setup. My goto used to be a Sennheiser MKH30 + MKH40 in a Rycote windshield. Those mics are probably outside your budget even used. Two decent small cardoid condensors with Rycote ball gags for wind protection in XY or ORTF should work well. Rode, Oktava, SE Electronics, Audio technica are names that seems to have less than 200 USD mics that fit.

I generally do not recommend shotguns except when you record dialogue outdoors and the mics are not to be seen.

Now, if you want to mix sound to PA that is something totally different. Then the SM58-s will come into play.